# shell history autocompletion and in-line coloring

Tags: shell, colors, autocomplete, command-history

How can I add support for autocompletion with coloring like in the screen shot below to any shell (preferably `bash`)? It was taken from [this video](https://youtu.be/ZA6flb7otNg?t=38s). I cannot seem to find anything that supports such feature.

[image: Project Photon Runs Docker and Rocket Containers via Vagrant and VMware Fusion]

Answer (score 1):

For `zsh` you can install oh-my-zsh (You can easily find it on github and see the installation guid. I can't give your more than 2 links because of my reputation)

`oh-my-zsh` contains lots of themes and plugins .

Installing some plugins do the job for you, and those plugins are :

[colorize](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/tree/master/plugins/colorize)

[zsh-autosuggestions](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions) (it's not a part of oh my zsh !)

Comment: The second plugin you mentioned helped me search further. This has already been asked [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109366/does-bash-have-similar-features-such-as-fishs-autosuggestions-and-highlighting) a couple of years ago. It seems that it's either [fish](http://fishshell.com) or [zsh-autosuggestions](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions) + [zsh-syntax-highlighting](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting), but then there were no ports for `bash`. I wonder what's the state now, although I couldn't find anything similar for it yet.

Comment: well,  you said **any shell** _(preferably bash)_