# How do I show a bash autocomplete result as a faded text in the terminal?

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, autocomplete

I'm using GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu). How do I see a preview of what happens if I press tab to autocomplete, similar to a fish shell. (Sorry, I'm new, so I may not be using the right terminology)

Comment: You mean what you see if you hit tab twice and there are more than one options?

Comment: No, more of like a definite function. So for instance mkdir, when i type mkd, it shows "ir" as greyed text

Comment: Right, OK. So _exactly_ what `fish` does. I was thinking maybe the list of completions offered on double-tab by `bash` would be enough. I don't think you can do what you want in `bash`. Or, rather, I don't think you can do it without a pretty complicated program written specifically for that. There's no bash option for it as far as I know. But let's see if anyone can come up with something clever. Could you please add a screenshot from `fish` showing what you mean for those not familiar with it?

Comment: Somehow relating: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/109366/315749

Comment: I see haha, that's really a pity. The intended outcome would be something like what @fra-san posted above. Thanks for all your help nonetheless!

Answer (score 0):

The link from @fra-san seems to be an answer. It uses [ble.sh](https://github.com/akinomyoga/ble.sh) ―Bash Line Editor― for Syntax highlighting, Enhanced completion and more.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/646375